# Chrome ignores label when it contains a strong element

Tags: html, google-chrome, accessibility

I have a form that includes a `label` element with a `strong` element inside it.

```html
<input id="priceCheck" type="checkbox">
<label for="priceCheck">
    <strong> Price Check </strong>
</label>
```

This is, as far as i understand, [spec compliant](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), as label may contain phrasing content and `strong` is defined as such.

However, in Google Chrome (both Android and Desktop), the content of the `label` is ignored in the accessibility tree, making the form element unlabelled (and thus inaccessible for screenreaders). In Firefox it works as expected.

Is this intended/known behavior? Should i file a Chrome bug for this, or am I missing something?

(I fixed this by just styling the `label` with CSS, but I still wanted to know whether this was somehow forbidden by the spec.)

Comment: you have a missing double quote on your `for="priceCheck` (missing `"` at end), this should work fine so maybe some strange parsing issue with that?

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo when copying, the original code was not missing any quotes. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original Answer - please see next level 2 heading for update.

The problem is not `<strong>` it is the way that chrome exposes labels to the accessibility tree on a checkbox.

You will notice that if you check the accessibility tree for the actual checkbox input, rather than the label, that it does link correctly.

This does not change if you move the styling to CSS, the label is still exposed as 'generic', but the input has 'label' (From label (for): label "Price Check") Price Check.

In fact it does not change if you remove the `<strong>` and add no CSS either.

It works fine in a screen reader as it is exposed on the input itself, this is the most important thing!

I think the confusion comes in the fact that a 'normal' text input the label does expose this information.

The below example shows this behaviour, I have added how each is exposed in comments.

```css
.priceCheckBold{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>All checkbox labels are exposed as 'WebArea > Generic > Ignored'</p>
<label for="priceCheckBoldInline"><strong>Price Check</strong></label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Ignored-->
<input id="priceCheckBoldInline" type="checkbox"/> 
<br/>
<label for="priceCheckBold" class="priceCheckBold">Price Check</label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Ignored-->
<input id="priceCheckBold" type="checkbox"/> 
<br/>
<label for="priceCheck">Price Check</label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Ignored-->
<input id="priceCheck" type="checkbox"/> 
<br/>
<hr/>
<p>All text input labels are exposed as 'WebArea > Generic > Label > Text "Price Check"'</p>
<label for="priceCheckTextBoldInline"><strong>Price Check</strong></label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Label > Text "Price Check" -->
<input id="priceCheckTextBoldInline" type="text"/> 
<br/>
<label for="priceCheckTextBold" class="priceCheckBold">Price Check</label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Label > Text "Price Check" -->
<input id="priceCheckTextBold" type="text"/> 
<br/>
<label for="priceCheckText">Price Check</label>  <!--WebArea > Generic > Label > Text "Price Check" -->
<input id="priceCheckText"/>
```

### Update after testing.

It appears this is a bug with Chrome after discussions with OP and testing.

**Do not use `<strong>`, `<em>` etc. within labels, instead style with CSS**

One other solution is to fall back to `<b>` in stead of `<strong>`. This still works.

If anything this is a better element to use as it only changes the appearance and does not add any importance to the word.

Comment: This does not reflect my situation. Both when looking at the tree in Chrome Devtools as well as when checking it with Chrome on Android + Talkback, when the <strong> element is there, the checkbox does not have a label/it is not read, without the <strong> element, it shows the "From label (for)..."/is read. I noticed this not by looking at the tree in devtools, but by Talkback not reading the label.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies, this appears to be a bug with Talkback, trying it now with `<span>` etc.

Comment: I would have guessed it was a bug in Chrome, since the output of the tree in devtools also changes depending on whether <strong> is there? Can't really test with a desktop screen reader though.

Comment: Yes you are correct, bug is in Chrome, it exposes ok to JAWs but NVDA doesn't like it either. When I tested first time I made a typo so it actually worked. Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: Another bit of information that may be related to this: It is not allowed to have any semantic element within an element with option role: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#Listbox (specifically the second paragraph: "As a flat string, the name does not contain any semantic information. Thus, if an option contains a semantic element, such as a heading, screen reader users will not have access to the semantics.").
I don't know where exactly this is specified, or if the same rules apply here, but it seems as this might not be a Chrome bug after all, but possibly under-specced.

Comment: @deltragon is this meant for another question? These are checkboxes not `<selects>` (which is what a listbox is basically related to). It is also the label causing an issue not the input.

Comment: Yes, i am aware, but I assumed that there might be similar rules what is allowed in a <option> as what is allowed in a <label> (as the practices call it, a "flat string"). This would make sense, since the label can also be set by eg. aria-label, which can only contain a string.

Comment: According to the HTML spec `<label>` elements (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) should be able to use Phrasing content (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) - this is an issue with Chrome exposing information correctly as it works in Firefox.